# Web API 2 Service - how to return error message when model object expected?

Tags: .net, vb.net, controller, asp.net-web-api2

So I have created a `GetValues` function in my controller to return the instance of a `demoModel` which is a complex model class.

This works fine when returning a successful data set. However if something doesn't validate how do I send a message back to the caller when the function expects the `demoModel` object?

Here is the controller code:

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class GetMyData
        Inherits ApiController

        'Note always expect 3 values coming in per the WebApiConfig
        Public Function GetValues(ByVal age As String, ByVal state As String, ByVal country As String) As demoModel 

            Dim dm As New demoModel()
            Dim myData As New createDemoData

            dm = myData.getTotalData(age,state,country)
            If Not dm.dataisvalid then
                'TODO Send Error message to the user   
            End If

            Return dm

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function return type from your model to `IHttpActionResul`

```vb
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class GetMyData
        Inherits ApiController

        Public Function GetValues(ByVal age As String, ByVal state As String, ByVal country As String) As IHttpActionResult

            Dim dm As New demoModel()
            Dim myData As New createDemoData

            dm = myData.getTotalData(age, state, country)
            If Not dm.dataisvalid Then
                return BadRequest("Return invalid data message to caller")  
            End If

            Return Ok(dm) 'return Ok (200) response with your model in the body

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

When calling the function the the response message will have the necessary contextual information in its payload.

Read up on [`Action Results in Web API 2`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) for more details on action results

Comment: This is what I was missing. This works perfectly, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Just return a Badrequest:

```
..
            If Not dm.dataisvalid then
                return BadRequest("Your error message")
            End If

            Return Ok(dm) 'need to wrap this with Ok
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error message: value of type "BadRequestErrorMessageResult" Can't be converted to demoModel. The return type expected is demoModel